# telerik report won't load into the MAUI web view

Tags: c#, maui, telerik-reporting

I'm trying to implement Telerik reporting into the MAUI app using webview as mentioned in the official documentation. It loads the view page with HTML5 Report viewer but after that it doesn't show the report as expected. It says no report. What can be the reason for this?

this is the documentation link: [https://docs.telerik.com/reporting/knowledge-base/displaying-telerik-report-in-net-maui-and-maui-blazor-applications](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

I'm expecting to display telerik report in the MAUI app

Comment: How is your REST service configured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like an issue with the settings of the [REST service](https://docs.telerik.com/reporting/embedding-reports/host-the-report-engine-remotely/telerik-reporting-rest-services/overview).

You can use the example REST service from installation (example C:\Program Files (x86)\Progress\Telerik Reporting R1 2023\Examples\CSharp.NET 6\ReportingRestServiceCorsDemo) or use the Visual Studio project template and [create a new one](https://docs.telerik.com/reporting/embedding-reports/host-the-report-engine-remotely/telerik-reporting-rest-services/asp.net-core-web-api-implementation/host-reports-service-in-.net-6-with-minimal-api).[image]

After you configure the REST service, set it in the ReportViewer ServiceUrl.